# How many aggregate Method used in Magical Records

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, aggregate-functions, magicalrecord

I am working on Magical Record. I have read document on MagicalRecord and also search on google.

After searching, i got there are aggregate functions like (sum, max,min). i want to know that is there is any other aggregate function.
Except these three aggregate functions Is there any other aggregate functions are Available in MagicalRecord.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What aggregate functions you are looking for exactly?

Comment: @AsifBilal As i mentioned in the question , aggregate functions like (sum, max,min). is there is any other also.